# outlook vba select messages in sub-folder

Tags: vba, outlook, gmail, hotmail

Outlook 2007  is configured with two email accounts:

- Account#1: Hotmail
- Account#2: Gmail

I would like to create a macro named simulating a user doing the following:

- Left click on a  within either the hotmail or gmail account.
- Highlight all messages within the folder previously selected.
- display a messageBox with the number of emails selected from this folder

I have tried several methods to define the folder, but its not working.  My suspicion is it would work on the default PST, but that isn't what I'm using.  Even tried using the method below to identify the specific folder I want to use.  It does print out a path, but I am not able to use that as a variable value directly.

Any suggestions?

=== Information ===

The following macro was used to obtain information about the account & folder locations:
http://www.gregthatcher.com/Scripts/VBA/Outlook/GetFolderInfo.aspx

1. Hotmail

   - Name: aaaaa
   - FolderPath: \@hotmail.com\aaaaa

-

2. Gmail

   - Name: bbbbb
   - FolderPath: \@gmail.com\bbbbb

---

```
' please add your values for Const emailAccount  and  Const folderToSelect
' To begin, launch: start_macro
'
' the macro will loop all folders and will check two things , folder name and account name,
' when both are matched , will make that folder the active one , then will select all emails
' from it and at final will issue number of selected items no other References are required
' than default ones

Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If



' please provide proper values for email account and folder name
Const emailAccount = "username@hotmail.com"
Const folderToSelect = "folder"



' declare some public variables
Dim mySession As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
Dim mySelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim my_folder As Outlook.folder

Sub start_macro()

    Dim some_folders As Outlook.Folders
    Dim a_fld As Variant
    Dim fld_10 As Outlook.folder

    Set mySession = Application.Session
    Set some_folders = mySession.Folders

    For Each a_fld In some_folders
        Set fld_10 = a_fld
        Call loop_subfolders_2(fld_10)
    Next a_fld

End Sub

Sub final_sub()
    If Not (my_folder Is Nothing) Then
        Set myExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
        Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = my_folder
        Call select_all_items(my_folder)
    Else
        MsgBox "There is no folder available for specified account !!!"
    End If


    End     'end the macro now

End Sub

Sub loop_subfolders_2(a_folder As Outlook.folder)

    Dim col_folders As Outlook.Folders
    Dim fld_1 As Outlook.folder
    Dim arr_1 As Variant

    Set col_folders = a_folder.Folders

    For Each fld_1 In col_folders
        If Left(fld_1.FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
            arr_1 = Split(fld_1.FolderPath, "\")
            'Debug.Print fld_1.Name & vbTab & arr_1(2) & vbTab & fld_1.FolderPath
            If InStr(LCase(emailAccount), "@gmail.com") > 0 Then
                If LCase(folderToSelect) = LCase(fld_1.Name) Then
                    If LCase(emailAccount) = LCase(arr_1(2)) Or arr_1(2) = "Personal Folders" Then
                        Set my_folder = fld_1
                        Call final_sub
                    Else
                        Call loop_subfolders_2(fld_1)
                    End If
                Else
                    Call loop_subfolders_2(fld_1)
                End If
            Else
                If LCase(folderToSelect) = LCase(fld_1.Name) And LCase(emailAccount) = LCase(arr_1(2)) Then
                    Set my_folder = fld_1
                    Call final_sub
                Else
                    Call loop_subfolders_2(fld_1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next fld_1

End Sub

Sub select_all_items(my_folder As Outlook.folder)

    Dim my_items As Outlook.Items
    Dim an_item As MailItem
    Dim a  As Long, b As Long

    Set my_items = my_folder.Items
    b = my_items.Count
    DoEvents
    'sleep 2000
    Set mySelection = myExplorer.Selection

    If CLng(Left(Application.Version, 2)) >= 14 Then
        On Error Resume Next    '   there are other folders that do not contains mail items
            For Each an_item In my_items
                If myExplorer.IsItemSelectableInView(an_item) Then
                    myExplorer.AddToSelection an_item
                Else
                End If
            Next an_item
        On Error GoTo 0
    Else
        myExplorer.Activate
        If b >= 2 Then
            For a = 1 To b - 1
                SendKeys "{DOWN}"
                'Sleep 50
            Next a
            For a = 1 To b - 1
                 SendKeys "^+{UP}"
'                'Sleep 50
            Next a
        End If
        DoEvents
        'sleep 2000
    End If
    Set my_items = Nothing
    Set mySelection = myExplorer.Selection
    MsgBox mySelection.Count

End Sub
```

Comment: if you highlight alle Messages in a Folder and display their number, in the end you just want the number of mails in the folder, is that right?

Comment: instead of doing some programming here, why don't you open the Folder (if necessary in a new window) look at the left bottom end of Outlook, where the number of mails is displayed always?

Comment: I'm open to other suggestions... this one isn't pretty for sure.

Comment: the initial ask doesn't define where this is intended to be used... its not merely to get the number of emails in the folder.  There is another macro which runs next to perform an action on all the messages.

If you have suggestions to make this simpler, I'm all for it.

Comment: using sendkeys might cause some comments from the pro's.... however it would be helpful to know what you want to do in the end. I guess the highlighting of all mails has some sense?  Why has the Folder to be choosen by right-click, instead of calling the macro for the Folder which is open in the active Outlook-Application?

Comment: The intent was to be able to run the macro if outlook already open or not.  In either case, I wouldn't necessarily have the account where this folder exists in focus.   If there is an easier way to give focus to <account>/folder than the way done here, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this one work?

```
Function GetFolder(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Outlook.folder
 Dim TestFolder As Outlook.folder
 Dim FoldersArray As Variant
 Dim i As Integer

On Error GoTo GetFolder_Error
 If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
 FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
 End If
 'Convert folderpath to array
 FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
 Set TestFolder = Application.Session.Folders.item(FoldersArray(0))
 If Not TestFolder Is Nothing Then
 For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
 Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
 Set SubFolders = TestFolder.Folders
 Set TestFolder = SubFolders.item(FoldersArray(i))
 If TestFolder Is Nothing Then
 Set GetFolder = Nothing
 End If
 Next
 End If
 'Return the TestFolder
 Set GetFolder = TestFolder
 Exit Function

GetFolder_Error:
'MsgBox ("Ordner für verschieben nicht gefunden")
 Set GetFolder = Nothing
 Exit Function
End Function
```

for me this works with all Folders, no matter if Primary or other box (but all of them being Exchange, but I do not think this maters)

e.g. These work:

```
Set mailitem.SaveSentMessageFolder = GetFolder(mailitem.SentOnBehalfOfName & "\inbox")

Dim Subfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set Subfolder = GetFolder(olfolder.FullFolderPath & "\erledigt")


Dim Subfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set Subfolder = GetFolder("someaccount\inbox")
```